# trigger chat bot from MS teams script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I need to trigger some of the @ commands you get when typing in microsoft teams, but through a script. When typing in teams, you can type @General for example, and it will recognize it as a command. However, testing remotely with my powershell script, it gets pasted as plain text and not recognized. Need help getting this to work. Currently using the PSTeams module to paste a message. The message gets pasted to the teams channel just fine. It's just not recognizing the @ as a command in teams

I need to mention a chatbot, followed by a command to trigger it

```
import-module -Name PSTeams

$teamsID - 'longlinkurlwithlotsofstuff'

Send-TeamsMessage `
    -URI $teamsID `
    -MessageTitle 'Message Title' `
    -MessageText "@Genie whoisoncall" `
    -Color Chocolate
```

Comment: Can you please share repro steps and sample code, so that we can check it from our end?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the PSTeams module (hopefully I've found the one you are using) I don't think it handles mentions as [the message body is being passed into the invoke-restmethod command 'as-is' in plaintext](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSTeams/blob/0f477d36607710cf0d111ab1fbdd44bd2e7b700c/Public/Send-TeamsMessage.ps1#L38).

Looking at the Microsoft Graph API version of sending a Teams message, [@mentions need to be passed in as an object itself with several properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-8---a-team-in-a-channel-message), which suggests it is complex functionality. Highly recommend using MS Graph if you can as it opens up advanced options for message sending.

Comment: Not looking like bots are supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/541478/how-to-send-a-chat-message-using-bot.html

Comment: @dcvl you can't mention uses from Teams webhooks. I used PowerAutomate to do this instead with a basic flow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it through script.

You can achieve this using commandlist property in manifest file. In commandlist you have to mention commands that your bot can recommend to users.

```
"commandLists": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "team",
                        "groupchat"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "Command 1",
                            "description": "Description of Command 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Command 2",
                            "description": "Description of Command 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#botscommandlists